# Changing only the Appstore name of an app

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an app which is already in the app store.
I only want to change the name of the app shown in the app store, without changing the name displayed on the device.

Comment: yes, the name in iTunes Connect is what will be displayed in the App Store. To change it though, you will need to submit a new app version.

Comment: @originaluser2 thanks for the fast reply! So there is no need to change the product name/ bundle name ? I saw lots of conflicting posts about it.

Comment: Well under the "Localized Information" section of the app in iTunes Connect, the name field info says **"The name of your app as it will appear on the App Store."** As far as I'm aware, the name you give to the app in Xcode is only the name used under the app icon when you install it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in iTunes Connect under **Localizable Information**, the name section says the following:
[image]

So yes, you can change it from iTunes Connect. You will need to upload a new version of the app in order to make this change though.

Comment: did this help you @oded-harth? be sure to accept if it did :)